# AngularJs Ng-Grid Add Link w/Id from another field to template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to get the hang of the great Ng-Grid module. I'm finding it to be a really great module, however i'm having a problem using an id number found in a cell as a link. My columnDefs options looks like this:

```
    columnDefs: [
        {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><a href="/#/monitor/ROWIDNUMBER">{{col.field}}</a></div>'},
        {field: 'description', displayName: 'Description'},
        {field: 'type', displayName: 'Type'}
    ]
```

I am wanting to add a /#/monitor/row.this.id to the href tag in the name column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the expression would be like

`<a href="/#/monitor/{{row.getProperty('id')}}">`

Comment: The difference is that `ROWIDNUMBER` is a special `ng-grid` value that is replaced during compile.

Comment: @Chandermani Thanks, that's right. I tried a bunch of different variations of that, but didn't think to try with quotes. Also, I had to escape the single quotes: {{row.getProperty(\'id\')}}

Answer (score 6):

You should use [`ng-href`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref) in the anchor tag and reference the `id` value with `{{row.entity.id}}`, like this:

```
{
  field: 'name',
  displayName: 'Name',
  cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><a ng-href="/#/monitor/{{row.entity.id}}">{{col.field}}</a></div>'
}
```